# Agrupamento usando o campo do tipo datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

Olá!

Uso o banco MSSQL Server e tenho uma tabela com um campo do tipo datetime e preciso fazer a contagem da quantidade de registros por data.

O problema é que, quando incluo esse campo do tipo datetime no select, o resultado não agrupa a contagem, pois o campo da data traz a hora, minuto e segundo.

Já usei o cast e o convert no campo para tirar o horário mas não consegui o resultado esperado.

Minha tabela é a seguinte:

| cod_empresa | dth_inclusao | chave_nota |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2023-11-01 10:15:50.000 | 50231125033514000466650220001952119528415728 |
| 3 | 2023-11-01 12:07:19.000 | 50231125033514000466650220001952129206506730 |
| 3 | 2023-11-01 12:13:22.000 | 50231125033514000466650220001952132650439385 |

Primeiro usei o seguinte select:

```
select
  cod_empresa,
  count(chave_nota) as quant
from tab_xml_nota
where cast(dth_inclusao as date)>='2023-11-01'
group by cod_empresa
```

Neste select acima, traz o resultado correto que seria:

| cod_empresa | quant |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 232 |
| 2 | 199 |
| 3 | 321 |

Porém, se eu incluir no select o campo tipo datetime, para mostrar a quantidade por data, não está agrupando o resultado.

Select usando o campo datetime:

```
select
  cod_empresa,
  convert(varchar,dth_inclusao,103) as data,
  count(chave_nota) as quant
from tab_xml_nota
where cast(dth_inclusao as date)>='2023-11-01'
and cod_empresa=3
group by cod_empresa,dth_inclusao
```

Resultado do select:

| cod_empresa | data | quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 01/11/2023 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/11/2023 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/11/2023 | 1 |

Observem que a quantidade é 1 para cada registro, sendo que deveria aparecer a quantidade total para cada data.

O resultado deveria ser como no exemplo abaixo:

| cod_empresa | data | quant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 01/11/2023 | 99 |
| 3 | 02/11/2023 | 122 |
| 3 | 03/11/2023 | 87 |

Usando o MSSQL Server 2014, o que preciso fazer para trazer o agrupamento correto?

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na falta do uso do `convert` no `group by` conforme demonstrado a seguir.

Foi informado o seguinte:

> Select usando o campo datetime:
>
> ```
> select
>   cod_empresa,
>   convert(varchar,dth_inclusao,103) as data,
>   count(chave_nota) as quant
> from tab_xml_nota
> where cast(dth_inclusao as date)>='2023-11-01'
> and cod_empresa=3
> group by cod_empresa,dth_inclusao
> ```

**O correto é usar o `convert(varchar,dth_inclusao,103)` na cláusula `GROUP BY` também. Ficando dessa forma:**

```
select
  cod_empresa,
  convert(varchar,dth_inclusao,103) as data,
  count(chave_nota) as quant
from tab_xml_nota
where cast(dth_inclusao as date)>='2023-11-01'
and cod_empresa=3
group by cod_empresa, convert(varchar,dth_inclusao,103)
```

**Observação:**
Visto que a falta do uso do `convert` faz com que o banco de dados considere até os milisegundos da data/hora do campo `dth_inclusao` o que torna, possívelmente, cada registro único, o banco de dados exibe a `data` esperada do `select` pois possui o `convert`, mas com o resultado inesperado igual a 1, pois no `group by` não possui o `convert`.

Answer (score 0):

Deve agrupar por empresa e por data:

```
SELECT cod_empresa,
       convert(char(10), dth_inclusao, 103) as data,
       count(chave_nota) as quant
  from tab_xml_nota
  where dth_inclusao >= '20231101'
  group by cod_empresa, convert(char(10), dth_inclusao, 103);
```

Não testei; espero que não tenha erros.

Como o tamanho do texto é fixo, de 10 caracteres, sugiro que utilize char(10) no lugar de varchar, na função convert. Aliás, evite utilizar varchar sem definir o tamanho pois haverá truncamento caso exceda 30.

Na cláusula WHERE acima evitei o uso de função; isso garante que o predicado é *sargable*.

Comment: Desculpem a demora em responder, mas deu certo. Funcionou corretamente.